# How to lock a directory between python processes in linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.4

I have two (or more) python processes running and want to create a concept similar to an [exclusion mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) for a shared resource.  The 'shared resource' in this case is a directory.  How might I most easily/standardly/etc implement a mutex?  A hidden `.lock` file that each process agrees to check and, if exists, appends their PID as a new row and then pops their PID when they have access to the file?

I basically just want to clear a directory and make sure no other process tries to read or write to it while I'm clearing it.

Is there a standard linux way of doing this? Maybe something I can just execute with a shell line from python?

Comment: Do you want to make sure that no other process or no other _Python_ process can r/w from that dir?

Comment: Ideally no other processes but since everything I'm writing right now is in python, just Python processes are OK.  That way I can control what they look for if that route is needed.  I'm hoping to find a pre-made solution for what seems like a common need though that's not specific to python or my application.

Answer (score 5):

**Linux**

There are two standard types of locking in Linux: [advisory locking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147392/what-is-advisory-locking-on-files-that-unix-systems-typically-employs) (specified in POSIX) and [mandatory locking](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/mandatory-locking.txt) (Linux-specific).

However, both of them may be applied only on files, but not directories. So yes, you need a lock-file. It assumes that all users should know about the lock-file and acquire the lock before accessing directory. Hence, mandatory locking will not help here, and you need advisory locking.

There are three kinds of advisory file locks in Linux:

- [`flock(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) (specified in POSIX);
- POSIX record locks, see "Advisory record locking" section in [`fcntl(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) and also [`lockf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lockf.3.html) wrapper (both specified in POSIX);
- Open file description locks, see [`fcntl(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) (Linux-specific, available in recent kernels).

---

**Python**

In Python, `flock()`, `lockf()` and `fcntl()` functions are available through [`fcntl`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html) module. There is also [`flock`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flock/) module that adds context-manager support to `fcntl.flock` function.

Here is an example:

```
import flock

with open('/my/dir/lockfile', 'w') as fp:
    with flock.Flock(fp, flock.LOCK_EX) as lock:
        pass # exclusive lock is acquired here
```

---

**PS.**

With this approach, you can not prevent a random process from accessing your directory, if it don't know about your lock-file. It is probably possible to implement a filesystem using [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) that will support mandatory directory locks, but I'm not aware of such implementations.

Comment: You can apply advisory locks on directories **just fine**, see [How can I lock a directory in C on a linux machine](//stackoverflow.com/q/8816941). Use `os.open()` to get a file handle for a directory.

Comment: The only downside is that you then don't have a place to record process information (a `.lock` file or *symlink* gives you a place to put that metadata).

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a flock lock on a directory. This is advisory (it won't stop processes that don't care about the lock touching the directory). The lock will persist until your program terminates. The code is pretty trivial.

```
lockfd = os.open('.',os.O_RDONLY)
fcntl.flock(lockfd,fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
```

If my understanding of the manpage is correct you can unlock it by simply doing.

```
os.close(lockfd)
```

But I haven't tested this as in my application it's desired for the lock to persist for the scripts entire run.