# Python: Lock directory

Tags: python, locking

AFAIK this code can be used to lock a directory:

```
class LockDirectory(object):
    def __init__(self, directory):
        assert os.path.exists(directory)
        self.directory = directory

    def __enter__(self):
        self.dir_fd = os.open(self.directory, os.O_RDONLY)
        try:
            fcntl.flock(self.dir_fd, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
        except IOError as ex:
            if ex.errno != errno.EAGAIN:
                raise
            raise Exception('Somebody else is locking %r - quitting.' % self.directory)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.dir_fd.close()
```

But according to the answers of this question locking a directoy is not possible: [Python: Lock a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52643622/python-lock-a-directory)

What is wrong with above code?

I only need to support current linux version. No Windows, Mac or other unix.

Comment: Is your own python process the only candidate to operate on the directory?

Comment: @FlyingTeller there is an other process who puts files into this directory, but this does not need to get locked. Only the python script which consumes the data needs locking.

Comment: if it's in the same process, why not use a "is_running" flag, so you don't fire the next processing if the current one isn't finished?

Comment: The question asks "How to lock a directory?" and the answer is "You can't, create a file that symbolizes a lock on the directory"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Cron is starting the process every N minutes. You suggest to use a "is_running" flag. That's why I want to lock the directory which the script operates on.

Comment: Not sure why you are asking another question then. `flock` applies to file handles, and and you discovered, `os.open()` lets you open a file handle for a directory. End of story.

Comment: The current question is "What is wrong with above code?". It is similar, but different than the other question.

Comment: It's rather close to a code review question too; I did find a minor issue (answer updated) but the approach is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I change your code a bit,add `return self` like most context manage do,then with `dup()`,the second context manage will fail.and the solution is simple,uncomment`fcntl.flock(self.dir_fd,fcntl.LOCK_UN)`

The mode used to open the file doesn't matter to flock.

and you cannot flock on NFS.

```
import os
import fcntl
import time
class LockDirectory(object):
    def __init__(self, directory):
        assert os.path.exists(directory)
        self.directory = directory

    def __enter__(self):
        self.dir_fd = os.open(self.directory, os.O_RDONLY)
        try:
            fcntl.flock(self.dir_fd, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
        except IOError as ex:             
            raise Exception('Somebody else is locking %r - quitting.' % self.directory)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        # fcntl.flock(self.dir_fd,fcntl.LOCK_UN)
        os.close(self.dir_fd)

def main():
    with LockDirectory("test") as lock:
        newfd = os.dup(lock.dir_fd)
    with LockDirectory("test") as lock2:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Great. Has any one fun making a little python lib on github+pypi from this?

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is a *read* lock, then there is only a minor error in the code you have. It is perfectly feasible to get a read lock on a directory.

You'll need to alter your `__exit__` function to use [`os.close()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.close) to close the file descriptor; a file descriptor is just an integer, and integers have no `.close()` method:

```
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    os.close(self.dir_fd)
```

The usual confusion for people that think you can't, are those that have tried with the `open()` function. Python won't let you open a directory node with that function because there is no point in creating a Python file object for a directory. Or perhaps there is an assumption that you wanted the OS to enforce access to the directory via the lock (as opposed to an advisory lock that a cooperative set of processes agree to obtain first before attempting access).

So no, there is nothing wrong with the code if all you want is an advisory lock, and are fine with this only working on Linux.

I'd drop the `directory` distinction from the code. The lock will work on any path that you have read access to. It is not exclusive to directories.

The downside of locking the directory is that this doesn't give you a place to store lock metadata. While `lsof` can give you the PID of the current owner of the lock, you may want to communicate some other information with the lock to help troubleshoot or automate lock breaking. A `.lock` file or symlink would let you record additional information. For example, Mercurial will create a symlink with the hostname, the PID namespace identifier (Linux only) and the PID in the target name; you can create such a symlink atomically, while writing that data to a file would require creating a file under a temp name followed by a rename.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here: [Python: Lock directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52815858/633961)

It is possible to lock a directory with this:

```
fcntl.flock(self.dir_fd, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
```

Of course this is a lock which every code which plays in this game need to check first.

AFAIK this is called "advisory lock".

Comment: You don't need to keep this anymore. I merged the questions. Please don't ask duplicated questions like that again.

Comment: @YvetteColomb what happens if I do it again?

Comment: it's not the worst thing that can happen, it's something we discourage. It creates more work for people to have to close them. If it were an ongoing habit it could result in disciplinary action, but that's in rare and persistent cases.

Answer (score 0):

I created this directory locker to manage directory access from multiple runtimes. I had multiple programs running in different runtimes that needed semaphore like behavior when accessing a directory because one of the programs running was a backup restore service, meaning that the entire directory had to be replaced while simultaneously other programs were reading or editing it.

Note that speed was not the main concern with this implementation as reading from and editing within the directory was not done with very high frequency. If you have very many files in the folder above the directory you wish to lock, this implementation is probably not well suited.

### Directory lock implementation

```py
import os
import threading
import time
import re
import uuid
import signal
from enum import Enum
from random import uniform
from typing import Optional
from common.custom_exceptions import DirectoryLockError


class LockUser(Enum):
    SLAVE = 0  # Multiple slaves allowed
    MASTER = 1  # Locks slave access, only one master at a time


class GlobalDirectoryLock:
    """
    Masters always have priority over slaves.
    Slaves can access simultaneously while no master lock is active.
    Only one master has access at a time.
    Can be used across multiple runtimes/threads simultaneously

    Do not store the lock or share between threads.
    Initialize it when you need one and discard it.

    Usage:
        with GlobalDirectoryLock(path, lock_type):
            # Do stuff
    """
    MASTER_LOCKFILE = ".master_lock"  # Master lock blocks directory
    MASTER_PENDING_LOCKFILE = ".pending_lock"  # Marks a pending master
    SLAVE_LOCKFILE = ".slave_lock"  # Marks directory as in use by non-master

    MASTER_REGEX = f"^{MASTER_LOCKFILE}"
    MASTER_PENDING_REGEX = f"^{MASTER_PENDING_LOCKFILE}"
    SLAVE_REGEX = f"^{SLAVE_LOCKFILE}"

    WAIT_TIME = 0.001  # seconds

    def __init__(
            self,
            filesystem_mount_path: str,
            lock_type: LockUser = LockUser.SLAVE,
    ):
        """
        :param filesystem_mount_path: The path to the directory locking target
        :param lock_type: The type of lock to use (slave or master)
        """
        self.__path = filesystem_mount_path
        self.__lock_type = lock_type

        self.__slave_lock: Optional[str] = None
        self.__master_lock: Optional[str] = None
        self.__pending_lock: Optional[str] = None
        self.__pending_time: Optional[int] = None
        self.__pending_uuid: Optional[str] = None

    @staticmethod
    def cleanup(path):
        """
        Clean up any lock files left over after a SIGKILL
        It is advisable to run this as a pre-startup job before any other programs start.
        """
        for filename in os.listdir(path):
            if re.search(GlobalDirectoryLock.MASTER_PENDING_REGEX, filename):
                os.remove(f"{path}/{filename}")
            elif re.search(GlobalDirectoryLock.SLAVE_REGEX, filename):
                os.remove(f"{path}/{filename}")
            elif filename == GlobalDirectoryLock.MASTER_REGEX:
                os.remove(f"{path}/{filename}")

    def __has_master(self) -> bool:
        """:returns: True if directory is currently locked by a master"""
        for filename in os.listdir(self.__path):
            if re.search(GlobalDirectoryLock.MASTER_REGEX, filename):
                return True

        return False

    def __has_slaves(self) -> bool:
        """:returns: True if directory currently has active slaves"""
        for filename in os.listdir(self.__path):
            if re.search(GlobalDirectoryLock.SLAVE_REGEX, filename):
                return True

        return False

    def __has_master_waiting(self) -> bool:
        """:returns: True if there are masters waiting for directory access"""
        for filename in os.listdir(self.__path):
            if re.search(GlobalDirectoryLock.MASTER_PENDING_REGEX, filename):
                return True

        return False

    def __is_next_master(self) -> bool:
        """:returns: True if this master is next in line for directory access"""
        for filename in os.listdir(self.__path):
            if re.search(GlobalDirectoryLock.MASTER_PENDING_REGEX, filename):
                f_name, uid, ns_time = filename.split("-")
                ns_time = int(ns_time)
                # If other pending file was created before this one
                if ns_time < self.__pending_time:
                    return False
                # If the times are exactly the same, compare uuid
                elif uid != self.__pending_uuid and ns_time == self.__pending_time:
                    return int(uid, base=16) < int(self.__pending_uuid, base=16)
        return True

    def __slave_acquire(self):
        if self.__slave_lock:
            raise DirectoryLockError(
                "SlaveLock: Do not reuse directory locks."
            )

        self.__slave_lock = \
            f"{self.__path}/" \
            f"{GlobalDirectoryLock.SLAVE_LOCKFILE}-" \
            f"{uuid.uuid4().hex}"

        while self.__has_master() or self.__has_master_waiting():
            time.sleep(GlobalDirectoryLock.WAIT_TIME)

        open(self.__slave_lock, 'w').close()

    def __master_acquire(self):
        if self.__pending_uuid:
            raise DirectoryLockError(
                "MasterLock: Do not reuse directory locks."
            )

        self.__pending_time = time.time_ns()
        self.__pending_uuid = uuid.uuid4().hex

        self.__master_pending = \
            f"{self.__path}/" \
            f"{GlobalDirectoryLock.MASTER_PENDING_LOCKFILE}-" \
            f"{self.__pending_uuid}-" \
            f"{self.__pending_time}"

        self.__master_lock = \
            f"{self.__path}/" \
            f"{GlobalDirectoryLock.MASTER_LOCKFILE}-" \
            f"{self.__pending_uuid}"

        open(self.__master_pending, 'w').close()
        while self.__has_master() or not self.__is_next_master():
            time.sleep(GlobalDirectoryLock.WAIT_TIME)

        # Create master lock before removing pending
        # Otherwise slaves might slip through before the master lock file is created
        open(self.__master_lock, 'x').close()
        os.remove(self.__master_pending)

        while self.__has_slaves():
            time.sleep(GlobalDirectoryLock.WAIT_TIME)

    def __master_release(self):
        if self.__master_lock and os.path.exists(self.__master_lock):
            os.remove(self.__master_lock)

    def __pending_release(self):
        if self.__pending_lock and os.path.exists(self.__pending_lock):
            os.remove(self.__master_pending)

    def __slave_release(self):
        if self.__slave_lock and os.path.exists(self.__slave_lock):
            os.remove(self.__slave_lock)

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.__lock_type == LockUser.MASTER:
            self.__master_acquire()
        else:
            self.__slave_acquire()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.__lock_type == LockUser.MASTER:
            self.__master_release()
            self.__pending_release()
        else:
            self.__slave_release()

        # Always raise errors if any occur
        return False
```

Here's a test I made to run it in multiple threads, I ran it for an hour or so without problems. Maybe someone could come up with a better one.

### Implementation test

```py
class GracefulKiller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.kill_now = False
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.exit_gracefully)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.exit_gracefully)

    def exit_gracefully(self, *args):
        self.kill_now = True


def lock_master(path: str, state: ThreadState):
    print("Request master")
    try:
        with GlobalDirectoryLock(path, LockUser.MASTER):
            random_sleep = uniform(0.0, 0.25)
            print(f"Master locked: sleep {random_sleep}")
            time.sleep(random_sleep)
    except Exception as err:
        state.failed = True
        state.set_error(err)
        return

    print(f"Master unlocked")


def lock_slave(path: str, state: ThreadState):
    print("Request slave")
    try:
        with GlobalDirectoryLock(path, LockUser.SLAVE):
            random_sleep = uniform(0.0, 0.25)
            print(f"Slave lock: sleep {random_sleep}")
            time.sleep(random_sleep)
    except Exception as err:
        state.failed = True
        state.set_error(err)

    print("Slave unlocked")


def while_loop_lock_slave(path: str, state: ThreadState):
    while not state.failed:
        time.sleep(uniform(0.0, 0.25))
        lock_slave(path, state)


def while_loop_lock_master(path: str, state: ThreadState):
    while not state.failed:
        time.sleep(uniform(1, 2.5))
        lock_master(path, state)


def threaded_test(path: str):
    slaves = 6
    masters = 3

    threads = []
    state = ThreadState()

    for i in range(slaves):
        threads.append(
            threading.Thread(
                target=while_loop_lock_slave,
                args=(path, state)
            )
        )

    for i in range(masters):
        threads.append(
            threading.Thread(
                target=while_loop_lock_master,
                args=(path, state)
            )
        )

    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    killer = GracefulKiller()
    all_done = False

    while not all_done:
        if killer.kill_now:
            state.failed = True
            
        all_done = True
        for thread in threads:
            if not thread.is_alive():
                thread.join()
            else:
                all_done = False

    err = state.get_error()
    if err:
        raise err

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Path to some directory that you want to lock
    dir_path = "../localstorage"

    # Probably best to do cleanup in a dedicated startup job
    GlobalDirectoryLock.cleanup(dir_path)

    # Run test
    threaded_test(dir_path)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you go with a simple lock file. As the question in the comment ([How to lock a directory between python processes in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592698/how-to-lock-a-directory-between-python-processes-in-linux)) suggests, there is no locking mechanism for **directories**, as opposed to files.
Lock files are used left and right on Linux, they are very transparent and easy to debug, so I would just go with that.
I am waiting to be challenged on this however!

Comment: Directories support advisory locking just fine, that other answer is simply wrong. All you need is a file handle, and the low-level `os.open()` call will let you open a directory file handle just fine.